# Why am I getting an invalid parameter error when updating a customer attribute in Shopware?

Tags: php, mysql, shopware

I am trying to update customer attribute in Shopware but am getting an error:

```
$builder = $this->container->get('models')->createQueryBuilder()
                   ->update(\Shopware\Models\Customer\Customer::class, 'customer')
                   ->set('customer.active',0)
                   ->where('customer.email= :email')
                   ->setParameter('email ' ,'xyz@test.com');
        $builder->getQuery()->execute();
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: Invalid
> parameter: token email is not defined in the query. in
> /var/www/html/shopware/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:134
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/shopware/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php(362):
> Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::unknownParameter('email ') #1
> /var/www/html/shopware/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php(319):
> Doctrine\ORM\Query->processParameterMappings(Array) #2
> /var/www/html/shopware/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php(962):
> Doctrine\ORM\Query->_doExecute() #3
> /var/www/html/shopware/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php(917):
> Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->executeIgnoreQueryCache(NULL, NULL) #4
> /var/www/html/shopware/custom/plugins/CustomPlugin/Controllers/Frontend/CustomPlugin.php(17):
> Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->execute() #5
> /var/www/html/shopware/engine/Library/Enlight/Controller/Action.php(193):
> Shopware_Controllers_Frontend_CustomPlugin->indexAction() # in
> /var/www/html/shopware/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php
> on line 134

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a where statement like this;

```
->where('customer.email = ?1')->setParameter(1 ,'xyz@test.com');
```